# Line shuffling multi-terabyte text file

Tags: python, shuffle, pypy

Problem: line shuffle a T terabyte text file containing n lines (same line can appear multiple times in the text file) given Z terabytes of RAM, where T = Z * 100. Quasi-shuffling is fine.

Presently I'm using [this Python implementation](https://github.com/alexandres/lexvec/blob/master/shuffle.py), which performs a quasi-shuffle, but it's somewhat slow. The algorithm is O(n) so I believe the slowness is caused by Python. I was thinking about re-implementing it in C but before doing that I was wondering if anyone knew of an existing solution.

Things that DO NOT work: GNU shuf (loads entire file to be shuffled in memory), GNU sort -R (hashes each line and so output identical lines adjacently).

Comment: Without looking at your code, I would strongly assume that the slowness is caused by I/O rather than Python (probably by seeking). Statistically speaking, do you need "perfect" shuffling or can you live with some trade-offs?

Comment: No, perfect shuffling not needed. The code does very little seeking. It loads x GB chunks in memory, shuffles them, and writes them to disk, for a total of K chunks such that K * x = T. Then it reads x / K bytes from each chunk, shuffles it, and writes it to the quasi-shuffled output file.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the code or the algorithm. You may want to run it through a profiler to find any hot spots. Consider adding the `Python` tag to your question for more visibility.

Comment: Alright, will add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following C++ implementation that is significantly faster: https://github.com/alexandres/terashuf